# dRAID, Parity 1 + 1 Distributed Spare Better than basic RAIDz2 for 5x12TB HDDs?

Tags: raid, zfs, software-raid, raidz, openzfs

Stumbled on dRAID recently and was [grokking the docs](https://openzfs.github.io/openzfs-docs/Basic%20Concepts/dRAID%20Howto.html) for OpenZFS on linux and I came away with a conclusion from the chart that I wanted to double check.

This is a brand new system that I'm currently building from scratch and trying to plot out how to use my 5x12TB HDD disks. My priorities:

1. Data Integrity
2. Storage capacity
3. I/O Performance
4. Uptime (home lab use)

I was happy with the capacity and write performance of RAIDz1, but because of the size of these drives, I couldn't risk a second drive failure while rebuilding a failed one (my impression was that a 12TB drive could take a day or so, linked chart seems to agree). So I was forced to choose RAIDz2, which hits my overall capacity, but I'm fine with that. What I was worried about was write performance hit (I might just have to run tests...for another post).

Anyway, the chart on dRAID docs in the link above suggests that even for 5 drives, having parity 1 (equivalent to RAIDz1) and a *distributed spare* shortens rebuild time to just about 4 hours and greatly reduces the load on the single new drive. **Faster rebuild for 1 drive and less write load seems to greatly diminish the risk of a second failed drive of this size while rebuilding the first as the burden is shared.**

[image: dRAID sequential resilver]

**Question 1**: I know that dRAID is for pools with many more disks, but other than complexity of setup (which I'll figure out), I only see upsides to choosing the dRAID route over RAIDz2.

Would you agree? Am I missing something about dRAID?

**Question 2**: More specifically, is the risk of a second drive failure reduced enough in the dRAID strategy so that I can get the capacity and performance back of only having 1 parity? My cake and eat it too?

**Update**: If anyone had some pointers on how to test this setup with the two methods, I'm down to try so that we could get some real data. I'm new to ZFS, so I'd need some help.

Answer (score 6):

Your are misreading the chart: it depicts a total of *90 disks*, with various groups/vdevs configuration. You can't extrapolate any useful info for a single 5x RAIDZ1 array.

DRAID is not meant for such low number of disks. The breakeven point probably is at around 24 disks, possibly more. Don't use it for a single 5-way RAIDZ1 array.

Regarding RAIDZ1, I would not use it for any array bigger than 4x 4 TB HDD except for very specific cases (it is fine with SSD, tough).

Comment: I would love your source material on where you got that "break-even" number of 24 disks. Break even for what? What's the trade off at that point between?

Comment: I use dRAID for 8 disks or greater. I even have it running on some 400-disk systems. My main consideration is rebuild time. There's no rule of thumb, but for home use, I think there's a trend towards overanalyzing the topic of "Which ZFS layout should I use?"

Comment: @brianclements it was the "ballpark number" discussed on the mailing list, if I remember it correctly. It is not an hard limit (but I would not go less than 8). The tradeoff vs RAIDZ is the two step resilver (raw copy + healing resilver) and a less intuitive available space calculation.